# how to remove duplicate from my question?

Tags: discussion

I have asked a question and it had been linked to something entirely different, from what I needed or wanted.

my original post [Next step for my First Program? NOT MENU ANYTHING](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050869/next-step-for-my-first-program-not-menu-anything)

Comment: Edit your original question and point out how it is NOT a duplicate. It's fruitless to ask a new question without even referencing the original question that "was/will be" closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I've put a complaint in. Its So annoying was obvious here because I needed some help.  Hey mate do they close my question now then? I was annoyed  thinking people was not going to read it , them passing thinking it been answered.

Answer (score 8):

Welcome Plutesci,

Some people (I'm one of them) interpreted your question to have been answered already here on this site, and therefore pointed you in the right direction to the duplicate *and apparently we were wrong.*  Therefore:

- please go back to your question
- edit it with the little grey edit button below your question
- tell us what in the duplicate you've already tried
- clarify your original question.

**Note:** You've also *answered your own question* in the meantime, instead of *editing your question*, so now it becomes totally confusing as to what you're really looking for, so sit back, think on how to edit your question, incorporating the current "answer" into it as well and ensure to provide *all the relevant information is **in your question*** and we'll have another go.

**Note 2:** this is a Q&A site very different from a normal forum.  The ideal is: one crystal clear question with one crystal clear answer or to say it with a picture:

[image]

*The little star in the middle is what Ask Ubuntu really is!*

## :-)